# ODBC-JDBC Gateway Error

Tags: neo4j, tableau-api

I'm trying to connect tableau 9.3 64-bit and neo4j 2.3.3 64bit using ODBC-JDBC Gateway 2.3 of Easysoft. But while setting up the DSN i'm facing an issue telling that java 1.7 is not certified to be used by this gateway. The Easysoft ODBC-JDBC Gateway works with 1.3.x to 1.7.x version of java. I don't understand what is the issue.